How to pass a class value adopting NSObject and NSCoding to a Swift function?
I would like to remove a warning when unarchiving objects so I tried to implement:
 func retrieveRepository(componentName:String, ofClass: AnyClass<NSObject, NSCoding>)->Any?{
        let fileUrl = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(componentName)
        do{
            let rawdata = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
            let optionalQueue = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: ofClass, from:rawdata)
            return optionalQueue
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }

On the ground unarchiveObject needs the name of the class where to unarchive that must adopt both NSObject and NSCoding. Yet this implementation is syntactically wrong. How to correctly implement it instead?

func retrieveRepository<T: NSObject & NSCoding>(componentName:String, ofClass: T.Type) -> T?? I didn't tested it, but a solution might be to use generic.

Or, if you want to write it with where T:... instead if <T: ...> it's possible. But I suggest you look at unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:) declaration/definition, because it's exactly what you're looking for.

You can re-write the function with a generic type like this:
func retrieveRepository<T: NSObject & NSCoding>(componentName: String, ofClass: T) -> Any? {
    let fileUrl = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(componentName)
    do {
        let rawdata = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
        let optionalQueue = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: T.self, from: rawdata)
        return optionalQueue
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}


Thanks you very much, I did ignore that construct.
Nonetheless, when I insert it a strange grey flag come out reporting Where 'T' = '[String : MKPlacemark].Type',
so defying the desire of having a generic function, even imagining how to insert it.
Moreover when I call it I receive:
Instance method 'retrieveRepository(componentName:ofClass:)' requires that '[String : MKPlacemark].Type' inherit from 'NSObject'
Type '[String : MKPlacemark].Type' cannot conform to 'NSCoding'

As a matter of fact I would like to pass in that case an array of strings and MKPlaceMark, both of which encodable, thus producing the error.

Just stating ofClass: NSDictionary.self might work then, but you'd have later to cast as: [String: MKPlacemark].

as @Larme said, NSKeyedUnarchiver works with the old NS family, i.e., NSDictionary, NSArray. You need to cast your data type to match these types, such as retrieveRepository(..., ofClass: someData as NSDictionary)

I got rid of genericity and used the final classes. The thing was not worth the effort.
